# I have an issue with my jQuery code and using Grails as technology then can i tag Grails?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have some code of jQuery and asked help for that here so for that I have tagged jQuery that is ok. But can I tag Grails for that question?

Comment: Is the usage of grails relevant to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fact that you're using Grails is relevant to the question, then yes, by all means you should tag it like that. If it's inconsequential, you shouldn't. A good way to decide that is to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your MCVE doesn't have any grails code in it, your shouldn't tag the question as such.